# explicit array type in mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, mapping

Is there a way to explicitly specify that a property is expected to be an array in the mapping?

Here is the relevant part of my json schema to generate the mapping: myArray should be an array. This is implicit done if i put 'myArray' with more than one value into the index. But i want that 'myArray' is also handled as array (in the response) if there is only one or zero values. Otherwise my elasticsearch clients are confused with the mapping from json to c# objects (Newtonsoft.Json).

```
"myArray":{
    "properties":{
        "start":{
            "type":"date",
            "format":"dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "end":{
            "type":"date",
            "format":"dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "nr":{
            "type":"long"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: Seconded -- this isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

In ES 1.x everything is treated as an array.  I would suggest upgrading.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_return_values.html

Comment: I already use Version 1.3.2. Unfortunately this is only available for fields.

Comment: can you post a full sample mapping and query